# awk to substitute value of field based on another

Tags: awk

I am trying to use `awk` to substitute the value of the `Classification` field `NF+1` with the value of the `CLINSIG` field `NF-1` if that value is `Benign`. I think the `awk` is close but currently I get an empty file.  What's wrong?

**input**

```
Chr Start   End Ref Alt Func.refGene    PopFreqMax  CLINSIG Classification
chr1    43395635    43395635    C   T   exonic  0.12    Benign  VUS
chr1    43396414    43396414    G   A   exonic  0.14    Benign  VUS
chr1    172410967   172410967   G   A   exonic  0.66    VUS
```

**awk**

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{ if ($(NF-1) == "Benign") sub($(NF+1)=$(NF-1); print $0 }' input
```

**desired output**

```
Chr Start   End Ref Alt Func.refGene    PopFreqMax  CLINSIG Classification
chr1    43395635    43395635    C   T   exonic  0.12    Benign  Benign
chr1    43396414    43396414    G   A   exonic  0.14    Benign  Benign
chr1    172410967   172410967   G   A   exonic  0.66    VUS
```

Comment: Don't you think it'd be worth mentioning and posting the syntax error your awk script is producing? Might make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: I apologize but the `awk` did run it was as @James Brown suspected, I was referring to the wrong `NF` variable. I am still trying to understand this as it makes things much easier. Thank you :)

Comment: The awk script posted in your question `awk -v OFS='\t' '{ if ($(NF-1) == "Benign") sub($(NF+1)=$(NF-1); print $0 }' input` **cannot** run as it contains a syntax error. If you ran some other awk script then, obviously, that's what you should have us looking at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably mean `Classification` field `NF`, not `NF+1`:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '$(NF-1)=="Benign" {$(NF)=$(NF-1)} {print $0 }' input
Chr Start   End Ref Alt Func.refGene    PopFreqMax  CLINSIG Classification
chr1    43395635        43395635        C       T       exonic  0.12    Benign Benign
chr1    43396414        43396414        G       A       exonic  0.14    Benign Benign
chr1    172410967       172410967       G       A       exonic  0.66    VUS
```